# Get array of objects if the objects have similarity in it in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let users = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ricardo",
    "serail_no": 463494,
    "occupation": "IT Specialist"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Saptak",
    "serail_no": 749694,
    "occupation": "Teacher"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Antonio",
    "serail_no": 406406,
    "occupation": "IT Specialist"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Dimitri",
    "serail_no": 2503853,
    "occupation": "Doctor"
  }
]
```

From the above Array List, I want to display only the objects which has same occupation in it.
So from the above list, if I take `occupation = IT Specialist`, then I ony want to display

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ricardo",
    "serail_no": 463494,
    "occupation": "IT Specialist"
  },{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Antonio",
    "serail_no": 406406,
    "occupation": "IT Specialist"
  }]
```

I tried it using filter method, but wasn't able to achieve it.
Will be very much grateful, if anyone helps me out in it with explanation.

Comment: What _specifically_ did you try? Seems like it would be trivial to use filter here - if you've had a problem with doing so, give a [mre].

Comment: `users.filter(({ occupation }) => occupation === "IT Specialist")`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
const filtered_users = users.filter(
  (user) => user.occupation === "IT Specialist",
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would use filter:

```js
const users = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ricardo",
    "serail_no": 463494,
    "occupation": "IT Specialist"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Saptak",
    "serail_no": 749694,
    "occupation": "Teacher"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Antonio",
    "serail_no": 406406,
    "occupation": "IT Specialist"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Dimitri",
    "serail_no": 2503853,
    "occupation": "Doctor"
  }
]

const ocupation = 'IT Specialist';

const filtered_users = users.filter((user) => user.occupation === ocupation);

console.log(filtered_users);

// output
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Ricardo',
    serail_no: 463494,
    occupation: 'IT Specialist'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Antonio',
    serail_no: 406406,
    occupation: 'IT Specialist'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter`

it takes a callback function (should return boolean) and returns a new array with the items which the comparison resulted true.

```
let filteredUsers = users.filter(function (user) {
  return user.occupation == "IT Specialist";
});
```

or if you want to get the Doctors and Teachers:

```
let filteredUsers = users.filter(function (user) {
  return ["Teacher", "Doctor"].includes(user.occupation)
})
```